# Objective C newbie: valueFor key works, .property doesn't

Tags: objective-c

2-day objective-C newbie here with a Ruby/Python background.

I'm currently stumped by how properties work.

I have a class 'Person' with attributes 'personName' and 'raise'.

If I call

```
Person *newEmployee = [[Person alloc]init]; 
NSString *pn = [newEmployee valueForKey:@"personName"];
NSLog(@"%@", pn);
```

everything works just fine & dandy. But if I call

```
Person *newEmployee = [[Person alloc]init]; 
NSString *pn = [newEmployee.personName];
NSLog(@"%@", pn);
```

I get the following error:

error: request for member 'personName' in something not a structure or union

I was under the impression the two were equivalent. The person.m class has `@synthesize personName` in it, person.h has `@property(readwrite, copy)NSString *personName;`

Any suggestions most appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have `#import "Person.h"` at the start of the file that your code snippets are from?

Comment: Many thanks. @class Person was imported from the header, but not the .m. I had a 'Receiver person is a forward class' error above the one mentioned, but thought it was unrelated. All works now - many thanks.

Comment: @unclaimedbaggage: Ah then that would be it. Forward declarations are always nutty, versus imports.

Answer (score 1):

When using the dot syntax to access properties you do not need the square brackets (unless you're sending a message to that property). Try this:

```
NSString *pn = newEmployee.personName;
```